# Remove the first star or dash in a string in R

Tags: regex, string, r

I have a data.frame. It looks like this:

```
name    state
Lily    *NY
Tom     NY,NJ
John    -PA,NJ
David   *SC,PA,NY
Jim     FL,PA
......
```

I want to clean my data frame in R. If the first character of the state is a letter or a number, keep it. But if the first character is a star or a dash, remove it. My goal is not to remove every first character so I can not use substring. Any solutions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general solution if you want to keep the first character only when it is a letter or a number:

```
df$state <- sub("^[^[:alnum:]]", "", df$state)
```

Comment: Similarly to @flodel 's comment: `[[:alnum:]]` matches all characters and numbers. It is equivalent to `[[0-9][A-Z][a-z]]`, but is more general because it will extend to any locale (for example it would still work correctly if you had chinese strings, provided you set your locale correctly).  By inserting the `^` inside the `[`, it is now matching all characters which are NOT alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df$state <- sub("^[\\*-]", "", df$state)
```

Comment: Hi  @flodel, I'm trying to learn regex off of SO. Can you please explain how your answer is different from this one `dat$state2 <- sub('^\\*', '', dat$state)`?

Comment: Yes, `^` is the beginning of the string anchor. `*` has a special meaning inside regular expressions, so you have to backslash it `\\*` for it to mean the star character. The dash however has no special meaning so `-` is just the dash character. `'^\\*'` will match a star at the beginning of a string. `'^\\*-'` will match a star followed by a dash at the beginning of a string. Now if you put them inside brackets, `'^[\\*-]'` will match a star OR a dash at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Thanks! I used to do it like this until now `dat$state2 <- sub("^\\*|^-", "", dat$state)` but your code looks nicer.